# PTIJ - Why does Rabeinu Hanan'el wear that hat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Every time I happen to glance over in the direction of Rabeinu Hanan'el on a daf of Gemara, it seems he is wearing an odd flat-shaped hat. What's with that — is it a fashion statement of some kind?

### [image]

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that [Rabbenu Hananel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chananel_ben_Chushiel) was Italian, for [Rabbenu Avraham ibn Daud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Daud) writes that his father [Rav Hushiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hushiel_ben_Elhanan) was one of four captives taken after leaving [Bari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bari). That being the case, given [styles from the period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1100%E2%80%931200_in_European_fashion#Headgear), it seems likely that he wore a [chaperon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaperon_(headgear)).

He therefore most likely looked like this:

[image]

As a tribute to this memorable hat, some editions of the Talmud add such a hat to Rabbenu Hannanel. Some editions even add them to others, so they don't feel left out.

Comment: Yes I know that Shechter disproved the 4 captive story...Its Purim "Torah".

Comment: Yes, now that you mentioned others getting the hat, I looked and saw Rabenu Gershom has one too, and there are probably more... my "joke" is deteriorating by the minute. But thank you for the art.

Comment: you are very welcome.

Answer (score 4):

It is a [Davar Yadua that many Talmidei Chachamim wear strange looking hats in the winter](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/judaism.stackexchange.com).  It is likely that at least some parts of the first printing of the Vilna Shas was completed in the winter, so as a "lo pelug", the printers left Rabbeinu Chananel's (and others') hat(s) on!